# Multiple database objects with the same ID using unique_together

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')
```

I want the individual `Bar` objects to be keyed on both an auto-incrementing ID *and* the parent `Foo` object. For each `Foo` I want the `Bar`s underneath to always be id'd `1,2,3`. The ultimate aim is to access `Bar`s via URIs such as:

```
/foos/1/bars/1
/foos/2/bars/1
```

Notice that there are *two* `Bar`s with the same ID, but the primary key comes from the uniqueness of the id's of both the `Bar` and its parent `Foo`.

I thought I'd found my answer in the `unique_together` attribute of the `Meta` class:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('foo', 'id')
```

But unfortunately this still results in a unique ID for each `Bar`. I always want the first `Bar` for each `Foo` to have an ID of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the ID, because that's allocated by the database and is always unique across the whole table. If you really want this, you will have to define a separate field and increase it each time you create a bar for your foo.

A naive implementation might be something like:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo_order = models.IntegerField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('foo', 'foo_order')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.foo_order:
            self.foo_order = self.bar_set.count() + 1
        super(Bar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

(Note that this is probably subject to all sorts of race conditions, so be careful.)

Now you can use the field combination in your view to get the relevant Bar:

```
def bar_view(request, foo_id, order):
    my_bar = Bar.objects.get(foo_id=foo_id, foo_order=order)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'd assumed something wrong about the id and pk fields - that pk would be the underlying, unique-per-table values while the id didn't have such constraints. Your solution makes sense, but yes - definitely have to be careful doing that. I'm surprised there isn't a built-in way of doing this, moreso if somebody else hasn't already implemented a library for it. Cheers again!

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, I don't actually need to store this identifier on any object. Rather than

```
/foos/1/bars/1
```

resulting in a lookup for a `Bar` with pk set to 1, I can just take the request and return something like

```
Foo.objects.get(id=1).bars.all()[0]
```

I.e. thereby mapping to the first Bar. so

```
/foos/n/bars/m
```

maps to the `m`th `Bar` under the `Foo` with primary key `n`.

Daniel's solution actually answers my original question, so I'm accepting that as the answer.